# Application for draw financial's graphs from CSV data

Tags: images, graphs, csv

I need to draw many financial's graphs about Bitcoin like there (example): https://bitcoinwisdom.com/ 
I have CSV data from here: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/

It is possible to draw by Gnuplot? Does it exist better and simpler software for this action?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically don't rely on links/like x program to detail requirements; explicitly list them. Also state OS - I'm hesitantly guessing you have a nix by the mention of Gnuplot but that's a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QtiPlot](http://www.qtiplot.com/). It's freeware and multiplatform and can import csv files. Open it and use the toolbar icon next to the save icons. The one with 123 and a table drawn on it (Import data files). Next choose your file, data separator, first line meaning and decimal separator. You can preview how the file will look when loaded in a table.

After that select a column and choose a graph from the Graph menu.

Here is an example with a file from the site you mentioned.

[image: QtiPlot main window]